# Link_to path in each do loop not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this Rails app, Users write Stories. A Story may be part of a Collection. Collections belong to the User who created it.

I am trying to show a single Story with links to the Collections it is part of. The collection.name part works but I can't get the  collection_path right. Thanks for your help.

stories/show.html.erb

```
  <% @story.collections.each do |collection| %>
  <%= link_to collection.name, collection_path %>
  <% end %>
```

rake routes for collections

```
  user_collections GET    /users/:user_id/collections(.:format)          collections#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/collections(.:format)          collections#create
     new_user_collection GET    /users/:user_id/collections/new(.:format)      collections#new
    edit_user_collection GET    /users/:user_id/collections/:id/edit(.:format) collections#edit
         user_collection GET    /users/:user_id/collections/:id(.:format)      collections#show
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users do
       resources :collections
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it by using the following with the help of Sebastián Palma who answered this earlier.**

```
 <% @story.collections.each do |collection| %>
        <%= link_to collection.name, user_collection_path(collection.user, collection), class: 'btn btn-lake' %>
      <% end %>
```